# Is it possible to beat the Wizard Scouts on page 3 without buying units?

Tags: highgrounds

After Penny Arcade linked it the other day, I decided to try the flash game Highgrounds.

I was making decent progress, lost a couple times but could usually beat the AI in a try or two, until I got to the Wizard Scouts on page 3. They're stomping all over me without even breaking a sweat; it's bad enough when they've got a couple 5 atk guys and a couple bolt 1 guys out, but once they get Jacen it's over.

Is it possible to win this fight without buying more units with real money? If so, how?

Comment: I have managed to beat all AI fights but I am losing most PvP as my deck is not good. Can you possibly make a recording and I might be able to give you some tips.

Comment: I know I HAVE beaten it, but once you've beaten a campaign match, it vanishes at the end of the week, so I can't play it again. Is this one where you need a ton of healers or wounders to make it work well?